# Debugging server code using IDLE - python

Tags: python, debugging, python-3.x, python-idle

In this python [code](https://github.com/shamhub/CS61A_Fall2012/tree/master/Guitar_heroine), I would like to debug `do_GET` method in `server.py` immediately when I click `playbutton` to send http `GET` request after launching server `python server.py` and connect from browser `http://localhost:port/`.

Is it possible to debug `do_GET` method using below IDLE tool?If no, Please recommend an alternative tool that helps debugging.

[image]

Comment: [`import pdb`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pdb.html) is the built-in python debugger that will run on any and all python IDE's. If you want an IDE with more advanced / easier to use debugging features, check out Spyder or PyCharm (PyCharm has more features, Spyder is easier to use in my opinion though)

Comment: can I set break point at `do_GET()` method using spyder or pycharm?

Comment: certainly, `f9` is the default hotkey for that